# How to remove image url on Autocomplete in Materialize CSS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, autocomplete, materialize

I have this JavaScript method that get all my data from a `department` table using API:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      //Autocomplete
      $(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://127.0.0.1/EnrollmentSystem/api/department/read.php',
          success: function(response) {
            var departmentArray = response;
            var dataDepartment = {};
            //console.log(departmentArray['records']['0'].name);
            console.log(departmentArray['records'].length);
            for (var i = 0; i < departmentArray['records'].length; i++) {
              console.log(departmentArray['records'][i]);
              dataDepartment[departmentArray['records'][i].name] = departmentArray['records'][i].name; //departmentArray[i].flag or null
            }
            $('input.autocomplete_department').autocomplete({
              data: dataDepartment,
            });
          }
        });
      });
  });
</script>
```

and i am calling it on my page using this one:

```
<div class="row lt-row-content input-field">
    <div class="col s12 m3 l3 lt-input-field">Department</div>
    <div class="col s12 m8 l8 lt-input-field"><input type="text" name="" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete_department lt-input-field"></div>
</div>
```

My concern is how can i remove the image shown on the Autocomplete?

[image]

As for the my Object only the **id** and **name** which i include on my models

```
class Department{
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "department";

    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }
...
```

This is the output of `console.log(departmentArray['records'][i]);`

[image]

Comment: What can be the result of console.log(departmentArray['records'][i]); ? Please try to attach it.

Comment: Can we see the source of the actual autocomplete row? The one that contains the "Z NEW DEPARTMENT" text? It looks like the jQuery autocomplete is adding an image but the docs doesn't suggest that it does that 

Answer (score 0):

```js
const departmentArray = {
  records: [
    { id: 1, name: 'DEPARTMENT 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'DEPARTMENT 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'DEPARTMENT 3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'DEPARTMENT 4' },
  ]
}

const dataDepartment = departmentArray.records.map(record => record.name);

$('#input').autocomplete({
  source: dataDepartment
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
<input id="input" type="text">
```

The [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete) documentation accepts a simple array of strings, so lets create that from your departmentArray response using [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var dataDepartment = departmentArray.records.map(record => record.name);
```

Also, autocomplete expects the options attribute `source` instead of `data`.

```
$('input.autocomplete_department').autocomplete({
  source: dataDepartment
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but nothing displayed on the autocomplete.

Comment: Does dataDepartment contain an array of strings?

Comment: It has a value of type: ```Array(10)
0: "A SAMPLE DEPARTMENT"
1: "A SAMPLE DEPARTMENT TWO"
...
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a snippet of my proposed implementation, can you see any difference between our implementations?

Comment: Does it not conflict with materialize css? I tried your suggestion, but nothing is being pop up in my screen.

Comment: Forget my suggestion. Can you simply inspect the broken image in the browser, find the appropriate css selector and then add .some-selector { display: none; } to your CSS?

Comment: Yeah, indeed. Putting **none** will not display the image but on the console i still get this error: ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Z%20NEW%20DEPARTMENT:1``` where **Z NEW DEPARTMENT** is what i put on input field, Is there anyway to get rid of it? I mean, tell the browser to not look for the image?

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a similar answer as the original post. The answer given by camaulay would be right if the original post was about Jquery autocomplete. It is not. The original post is about Materializecss autocomplete and it should be data and NOT source for the list of autocomplete elements. `
// copy/pasted from https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
    });
  });`[codepen example.][1]
```

See `"Apple": null` - the *null* value is the way to suppress the image in the Materializecss autocomplete.